# How do notifications work on linux?

Tags: linux, d-bus, notifications, libnotify

I use ArchLinux, but this should be irrelevant, other than being the reason why I often refer to [its wiki pages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/).

I think don't have a really clear understanding of how notifications work, and what are the "players" interacting for notifications to work:

- how many players are involeved?
- What is a notification server, and what does it *serve*?
- What is a notification client, and what does it *do*?
- What is this `notify-send` thing I can use to make a notification pop up? Is *it* the (well, *a*) client?
- What is a *notification daemon*?
- And what is the role of [`libnotify`](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=libnotify)?

---

In an attempt to understand that and to set up notifications on my system, I referred to [this wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_notifications).¹

I've tried with [`notification-daemon`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/notification-daemon) first. This doesn't work just upon installing it. For a call to `notify-send` to be successful, one has to either launch it (it means executing `/usr/lib/notification-daemon-1.0/notification-daemon`) manually, autostart it somehow, or create a file at `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` with this content

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon-1.0/notification-daemon
```

Then I tried [`dunst`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dunst), but that, as soon as installed, just works, in the sense that `notify-send` just works. I think this is fundamentally because it starts itself upon the first call to `notify-send` (which means that I initally had the impression that it worked also after I had uninstalled it; that's because the `dunst` process was running), but how does it do that?

And these two, `notification-daemon` and `dunst` are both under the section [Notification servers > Standalone](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_notifications#Standalone), but they are also called "notification daemons"; does it mean that *notification daemon* and *notification server* are synonyms? If not, where's the difference?

And from the perspecitve of the user (me), is the difference between those two aesthetic? I mean, when one is running vs the other is running, I see that the notification looks different. Incidentally, here comes the question "what are they serving?", because it looks to me that they are only waiting for some other tool to send them notifications, so that they can show them in a nice way. Or are both of them doing both things? In either case, where do the notifications originally come from? How do they get to notification boxes?

Anyway, what if I want to do custom stuff with the notifications? Say that I want to get them all and have my own shell script that, say, just appends them in a file `~/notifications`. Would that mean I'm writing my own notification server? Or client? Or what?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to experiment with the idea that I can show notifications in the [`xmobar`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar) status bar (which I use with XMonad window manager), so I'm trying to understand all the bits.

I've also given a look at [`statnot`](https://github.com/halhen/statnot) which seems very very skinny and without frills, but with reference to the my previous paragraph, it feels like using `statnot` would still mean that I would still have to write a configuration that, via the function `update_text`, calls into some API that xmobar or xmonad exposes. This way I would not have control on, say, how many notifications I want to show at a time.

I'm getting a bit lost :/

Trying to understand the implications on this question of mine from the [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html) has been unsuccessful :D

---

(¹) But [I had a pre-existing "bug" in my `~/.xinitrc`, so I had to solve that first](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2145202#p2145202).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a notification server, and what does it serve?

In general terminology, a *server* is a program that clients connect to in some way (whether over network or over local IPC mechanisms). The notification server is therefore a program that accepts "show a notification" requests from clients, and shows notifications on their behalf.

> What is a notification client, and what does it do?

Any program that *uses* a notification server becomes a "notification client". This is again not a notification-specific term; it's about the general architecture.

> What is this notify-send think I can use to make a notification pop up? Is it the (well, a) client?

Yes, it's a client in this case. Its purpose is mostly just so that *you* can make notifications pop up; apps don't run it because they can perform the same operations directly in their own process.

> What is a notification daemon?

Exactly the same thing as a notification server.

The term 'daemon' has a somewhat different meaning; it refers to any kind of *background* service, whether it is a "server" or not – but in this case, the program that's responsible for showing the actual notification popups is both a server and a daemon at the same time (as it runs in background like a daemon, and accepts requests like a service).

> And what is the role of libnotify?

It's a small library that can be used by notification clients, to abstract away the specifics of the IPC mechanism being used (as well as the differences between protocol versions). Instead of needing to know about D-Bus and interfaces, the program just does `notify_notification_new(...)`.

(That said, many apps choose to implement the communications directly, e.g. using libdbus to make the necessary calls – it's a pretty simple protocol so both options are probably equally common.)

The protocol that's used between a client (like libnotify) and a notification server is also often misnamed "the libnotify protocol".

> And from the perspecitve of the user (me), is the difference between those two aesthetic? I mean, when one is running vs the other is running, I see that the notification looks different

That is *literally* the difference. The idea is that each desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, etc.) would have its own notification server that would show popups tailored for that desktop environment – appearance, settings, behavior, etc.

(It might not necessarily even be a separate daemon; e.g. in GNOME and in AwesomeWM the notification service is provided by the desktop shell itself.)

> Incidentally, here comes the question "what are they serving?", because it looks to me that they are only waiting for some other tool to send them notifications, so that they can show them in a nice way.

Yes, but "waiting for some other tool to send them notifications" is what counts as "serving" something. A service doesn't necessarily have to return some data as a result – there are plenty of services in any system that are more-or-less one-way, i.e. whose job is to *do* something rather than to *return* something.

> Anyway, what if I want to do custom stuff with the notifications? Say that I want to get them all and have my own shell script that, say, just appends them in a file ~/notifications. Would that mean I'm writing my own notification server? Or client? Or what?

You would be writing your own "notification server" if it implements the notification protocol, i.e. the agreed-upon method by which clients communicate with it. For most Linux systems, the de facto standard is implementing the "org.freedesktop.Notifications" interface through D-Bus – if you implement it, you have a notification server.

(Though it will be really difficult to do that through a shell script, but it can be done in about 10 lines of Python or Perl, given that the interface consists of approximately two functions.)

> I've tried with notification-daemon first. This doesn't work just upon installing it. For a call to notify-send to be successful, one has to either launch it (it means executing /usr/lib/notification-daemon-1.0/notification-daemon) manually, autostart it somehow, or create a file at /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service with this content
>
> ```
> [D-BUS Service]
> Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
> Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon-1.0/notification-daemon
> ```

The absence of this file is deliberate, because it implies that there is only one program providing this specific service – while in reality one may have multiple desktop environments installed, each having its own notification service, and D-Bus has no mechanism to prioritize one implementation or the other.

So while many other D-Bus services are autostartable, most notification servers deliberately aren't, so that they wouldn't be chosen to be started in the "wrong" desktop environment. The desktop environment is meant to "manually" start the appropriate service, e.g. you might start it from your `~/.xinitrc` if that's what you do.

> Then I tried dunst, but that, as soon as installed, just works, in the sense that notify-send just works. I think this is fundamentally because it starts itself upon the first call to notify-send (which means that I initally had the impression that it worked also after I had uninstalled it; that's because the dunst process was running), but how does it do that?

It uses the exact same method that you described above – its package actually includes a D-Bus .service file:

```
$ cat /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.knopwob.dunst.service
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/bin/dunst
SystemdService=dunst.service
```

The only difference is that the actual file is not named after the service it supposedly provides (dbus-daemon doesn't enforce this requirement for "user" services).

> I've also given a look at statnot which seems very very skinny and without frills, but with reference to the my previous paragraph, it feels like using statnot would still mean that I would still have to write a configuration that, via the function update_text, calls into some API that xmobar or xmonad exposes. This way I would not have control on, say, how many notifications I want to show at a time.

That seems to be unavoidable. If you want custom logic, then you need to write custom logic.

For example, I had once written a notification daemon that [uses dzen2](https://git.nullroute.lt/hacks/dzenify.git/tree/dzenify) as the "popup". You can implement any logic you like in the Notify() method.

Comment: Very clear explanation! However, would you mind clarify something with respect to the [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html)? There I read that _"The server should implement the `org.freedesktop.Notifications` interface […]"_, from which I'd deduce that your `DzenifyService` is such a server. But at the same page, I read of `org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify` that _"Sends a notification to the notification server"_, so what's that? The notification server sends notifications to the notification server?

Comment: On the other hand, your `DzenifyService` uses dzen2 to actually show the popup visually, so I'd have called dzen2 the _server_. And your `DzenifyService` would be the client?

Comment: You could say that DzenifyService is simultaneously a server for the Notification API and a client for dzen2 (if it can even be called that, given that dzen2 doesn't actually run like a server process normally; it's typically a regular process/tool). But the latter half is not relevant to the example; what's relevant is that the Python script is a server for the Notification API and does *something* to make a pop-up show whenever it receives the Notify call, so you could also consider both processes as a single unit or even ignore dzen2 completely.

Comment: Oh, ok, so your `DzenifyService` is the notification server, and it's only delegating the graphical work to an existing program which is dzen2! But that's not different from it doing the work itself, as far as notification sever-client goes.

Comment: FYI, I've asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78169917/am-i-wrong-or-dunstnotify-send-violates-the-desktop-notification-specification) about something strange I've noticed about `notify-send` and how it reports the IDs via the `-p` option.

Answer (score 0):

> I think don't have a really clear understanding of how notifications work, and what are the "players" interacting for notifications to work:

Technically (and implementation-agnostic) you'll need at least a daemon handling notifications (e.g. receiving and processing them), a way for other processes to hand over notifications to said daemon, and an agreement (e.g. a standard) on what the notification data passed from an application to the daemon looks like so it can be processed.

To fill in the blanks for most Linux desktop environments:

- There's a notifications daemon (many desktop environments like Gnome bring their own implementations that are started with a user session; in other cases if you use a more minimal desktop, you may have to set-up a notification daemon service for this; there are different implementations of the latter available, mako to name one for wayland desktops).
- The notification daemon (if it complies with the Desktop Notifications Specification) exposes a D-BUS interface (D-BUS is a message-passing system that allows communication between process) which then is used by other processes to send notifications to the daemon.
- The Desktop Notifications Specification defines what the daemon expects to have passed as a valid notification and what parameters a notification can have (I'd recommend reading the spec to dive deeper into this: [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html#protocol))

> And what is the role of libnotify?

Libnotify is, simply put, a library that provides functionality to send Desktop Notifications Specification compliant notifications to a notifications daemon that also complies to this standard. If you're building an application that should support desktop notifications on linux, you could use libnotify to achieve that.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but do you see that the link you've posted is precisely the second to last link in my question? I said I've gone through that, but it did not really help me much. You've given some good general information, but not really something that I can turn in practice.